C++ для разработки под андроид
Подскажите, пожалуйста, фреймворки помимо qt для мобильной разработки под андроид, спасибо)

@AlexF Библиотеки на С++ можно и в обычной Android Studio писать, и в Eclipse до этого. И даже без них, если самостоятельно дергать toolchain из android NDK. Вопрос-то про фреймворки.

Под андроид вообще никто не пишет на C++ - это моральное самоубийство. Посмотри рекомендации на андроид есть свой собстрвенный оконный фреймворк, который идеально работает на разных версиях андроид без танцев с бубном. Мой выбор (рекомендация Google) Kotlin + Android SDK из коробки.
Если у тебя прям жесткая 3D игра где каждый байт на счету, то Xamarin Android SDK. Но так работают уже большие студии, отдельному программисту это не нужно.

Такое ощущение, что ответ написан кем-то, знакомым с андроид разработкой только по ютуб туториалам или курсам каким-нибудь. Оконнный фреймворк андроида с java api - это наверное один из самых кривых, ущербных и нестабильных api для широко распространных систем. Гугл даже официальный набор костылей (jetpack) выпускает. Xamarin был для разработки приложений на C# для знакомых с .net, который просто добавлял еще больше оверхеда, благо его поддержка уже прекращена. Без С/С++ писать на адроиде хоть что-то более-менее производительное, для обработки мультимедиа, весьма затруднительно.

Надо пологать, что он служит для тех же целей, т.е. разработки приложений на C# для людей, знакомых с .net.

Вы правы, я не ообо интересусь Андроид разработкой. Меня всегда больше интересовало писать сервисы на C, C++, Java, JavaScript. Просто те проекты с которыми сталкивался на том-же upwork в лвиной доле это конечно Flutter, Java, Scala, реже C#. Просто я очень давно пишу на Си подобных и реально такая ерись как писать на Си под андроид, это нереальная дикось даже для меня. И как вариант я предложил пару возможных часто испольщуемых замен. Не пойму зачем сразу ругаться и закидывать палками.

По поводу "Оконнный фреймворк андроида с java api - это наверное один из самых кривых, ущербных и нестабильных api для широко распространных систем.". Не смогу с вами согласиться, его главный козырь - он отлично продукментирован. И если что-то не так, то всегда можно почитать документацию и решить проблему. Плюс он имеет отличный сговорчивый комюнити, где всегда можно спросить что не так.
